# Validation error during ink contract metadata validation

Tags: ink

I am trying to validate an ink contract:

```json
{
    "source": {
        "hash": "0xb7233c251935e3ea430f99396cbb9430dd44ac2d07e447fd2003e81ad1d4a577",
        "language": "ink! 3.3.1",
        "compiler": "rustc 1.65.0-nightly"
    },
    "contract": {
        "name": "my_psp22_metadata",
        "version": "2.2.0",
        "authors": [
            "Author's email"
        ]
    },
}
```

The contract was successfully [deployed on shiden](https://polkaholic.io/tx/0x2c986a6cb47b94a9e50f5d3f660e0f37177989594eb087bf7309c2e15e2340c8) so i am sure that metadata is correct.

The problem is that i can't validate the metadata and interact with the contract.
I tested validation on the latest json schema from the ink master branch.
Here is the errors - https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/EyN4d6Az

I guess the schema is incorrect or outdated.

Comment: Can you open an issue in the ink! repository and tag me? Make sure to include a link link to the contract repo and the version of `cargo-contract` you're using to build the contract

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non sequitur. Successful deployment does not tell you whether your metadata is valid. The metadata isn't uploaded to the chain and hence not validated. The only thing you learned is that the chosen constructor didn't revert for the input you passed. That said, an outdated schema seems to be the most likely conclusion (or a schema that does not cover all corner cases). Best to open an issue in the ink! repo with a minimal reproducer.